# all data duplicate in my associative array

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping

i´m building a script that get data from my db, and in this data i have a `urls`. In this `URLs` i need search in article if contain any words or phrase and if contain it, get link.

to create this logic, i´m using laravel and library `Goutte\Client;`

i´m building a first associative array in my first function, and after i´m sending this array to me second function:

my data received in my second function it´s:

```
array:318 [▼
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "order" => "PEDIDO#20002"
    "order_name" => ""
    "post_url" => ""
    "anchor_text" => ""
    "url" => ""
    "type_link" => ""
  ]
```

this data it´s ok. Now i´m doing a pettition to url to do a scrapping and check if node->text() it´s equal to anchor_text. If it´s equal, i build a new associative array with data from my db and scrapping result. I want to do this, becasuse after i want to build a page with this data to show it more beautiful.

my actual code it´s:

```
for($i=1; $i<count($allOrders); $i++){
    $this->url = $allOrders[$i]["post_url"];
    $this->anchor_text = $allOrders[$i]["anchor_text"];
    $this->order = $allOrders[$i]["order"];
    $this->order_name = $allOrders[$i]["order_name"];
    $this->type_link = $allOrders[$i]["type_link"];

    if(isset($allOrders[$i]["post_url"])){
        $client = new Client();
        try{
            $website = $client->request('GET', $this->url);
            $website->filter('a')->each(function ($node) {
                if($node->text() === $this->anchor_text){
                    $data = [
                        'pedido' => $this->order,
                        'articulo'  => $this->order_name,
                        'url' => $this->url,
                        'anchor_text' => $this->anchor_text,
                        'tipo'  => $this->type_link,
                        // scraping web result
                        'result_test' => $node->text(),
                        'link_rel'  => $node->attr('rel'),
                    ];
                        
                    array_push($this->result_ok, $data);
                }else{
                    $data = [
                        'pedido' => $this->order,
                        'articulo'  => $this->order_name,
                        'url' => $this->url,
                        'anchor_text' => $this->anchor_text,
                        'tipo'  => $this->type_link,
                        // scraping web result
                        'result_test' => $node->text(),
                        'link_rel'  => $node->attr('rel'),
                    ];
                        
                    array_push($this->result_ko, $data);
                }
            });
                
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($this->result_ok);
    echo "</pre";
}// end for
```

My result in pretty `var_dump()` it´s:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["pedido"]=>
    string(36) "PEDIDO#20002"
    ["articulo"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["url"]=>
    string(108) ""
    ["anchor_text"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(6) ""
    ["result_test"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["link_rel"]=>
    string(19) ""
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["pedido"]=>
    string(36) "PEDIDO#20002"
    ["articulo"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["url"]=>
    string(108) ""
    ["anchor_text"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(6) ""
    ["result_test"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["link_rel"]=>
    string(19) ""
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["pedido"]=>
    string(36) "PEDIDO#20002"
    ["articulo"]=>
    string(21) ""
    ["url"]=>
    string(108) ""
    ["anchor_text"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(6) ""
    ["result_test"]=>
    string(20) ""
    ["link_rel"]=>
    string(19) ""
  }
}
```

I removed all data, because it´s a sensitive information, but all my arrays it´s with same information. Also my server delay many time to show data....

i Hope that anybody can help me.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Most likely explanation I can see, with the current lack of details, is that there is probably more than just one single link with the matching text on the page you are scraping ...?

Comment: If you put `var_dump($node)` inside the `each()` loop, do you see different values?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your response. yes if i write ```var_dump()``` in ```loop``` i can seee differente values